# Changing permissions on the symlink directory, not the target directory it points to

Tags: linux, permissions

I have the following:

```
~ ❯ ls /var/www/mechanic360.local/wp-content/themes
Permissions Size User Group Date Modified Name
lrwxrwxrwx    53 http http  17 Oct 12:35  fis -> /home/j/code/mechanic360.io/wordpress_theme/fis/theme
.rw-r--r--    28 http http  15 Oct 20:51  index.php
drwxr-xr-x     - http http  15 Oct 20:51  twentytwentyone
```

Notice the permissions for `fis`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx    53 http http  17 Oct 12:35  fis
```

I want those changed to:

```
lrwxrwxr--    53 http http  17 Oct 12:35  fis
```

How do I do that? I tried `chmod 774 ./fis` when in the `/var/www/mechanic360.local/wp-content/themes` directory, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Someone on Twitter sent me a [screenshot of their setup](https://i.imgur.com/2N6LG26.jpg), and their symlink (`classic-editor`) seems to have the permissions that I want. But to answer your question, WordPress isn't recognising my theme through the symlink I have.

Comment: I guess you’re right, they might be on OSX, so on Linux, a symlink always has 777?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag, you can't do that, and it wouldn't matter anyway:

[`symlink(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html):

> The permissions of a symbolic link are irrelevant; the ownership
> is ignored when following the link, but is checked when removal
> or renaming of the link is requested and the link is in a
> directory with the sticky bit (S_ISVTX) set.

[`symlink(7)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html):

> On Linux, the permissions of an ordinary symbolic link are not
> used in any operations; the permissions are always 0777 (read,
> write, and execute for all user categories), and can't be
> changed.

Note that extraordinary symbolic links may behave differently, e.g. the permissions bits for the symlinks you'd see in `/proc/$pid/fd` show the open file descriptor's permissions.

Comment: Note also software like apache and samba may manually read the ownership permissions to determine if they should follow the symlink.  This could affect wordpress depending on apache's settings.